# Intel Galileo linux image doesn't seem to support the "sudo" or "apt-get" command

Tags: linux

I updated the firmware for my gen 1 board to 1.1.0.
I'm logged in as the root.
My intel galileo is connected to the internet and can ping various websites.
Node,python, and curl are all recognized commands but sudo and apt-get are not. 
Any help?

Comment: Sorry for your trouble, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)